# Unable to resolve module react-native - React Native 0.38.0

Tags: ios, node.js, xcode, react-native

We use GitHub Issues for bugs.

I recently created a new project using `react-native init MyProject`. The app ran fine initially.

However now, when I run `react-native run-ios` or try to use xcode to run the app. I get the following error screen.

[image]

I have followed the suggested instructions and have ran the following

`rm -rf node_modules
rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-* --reset-cache
rm -rf node_modules/react-native/packager/packager.sh --reset-cache
npm cache clean
npm i`

But I still experience the same problem

I have verified that `react-native` is in fact installed at the correct location.

- React Native version: 0.38.0
- Platform: iOS
- Operating System: MacOS

Comment: Not sure if related, but the command you ran to reset the packager cache should be `./node_modules/react-native/packager/packager.sh --reset-cache`, not `rm -rf node_modules/...`